# Search for id through database table Java not working

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to understand why I can not search more than one record in a database with Java. It is a Java jsp application but I seems to struggle to figure out where the issue is. I am a beginner with jsp but I am sure would not make any difference

```
 try{  
  String myDriver = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver";//db driver 
  String myUrl = database;//connect to db
  Class.forName(myDriver);
  Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, user, password);//authenticating on database
  String query = "SELECT Cus_ID, Cus_name, Cus_surname, Cus_mail, Cus_Address, Cus_telephone FROM customerdb";//mysql select statement 
  PreparedStatement sta = conn.prepareStatement(query); //prepared statement 
  ResultSet rst = sta.executeQuery(query);


     while (rst.next())
  {


    String cusid = rst.getString("Cus_ID"); //variable to retrieve the customer from the database
    String cusn = rst.getString("Cus_name");
    String cussn = rst.getString("Cus_surname");
    String cusm = rst.getString("Cus_mail");
    String cusaddr = rst.getString("Cus_Address");
    String custel = rst.getString("Cus_telephone");


  if(!(customer.equals(cusid))){


      request.setAttribute("al", "user not found");                       
      request.getRequestDispatcher("account.jsp").forward(request, response); //and user will stay on login page


  }if(customer.equals(cusid)){

      System.out.println("hello" + cusid);
      request.setAttribute("ID", cusid);
      request.setAttribute("name", cusn);
      request.setAttribute("surname", cussn);
      request.setAttribute("mail", cusm);
      request.setAttribute("address", cusaddr);
      request.setAttribute("telephone", custel); 

      request.getRequestDispatcher("account.jsp").forward(request, response);
  }else{

  }
  }
}catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException | HeadlessException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(LogInController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `i can not search more than one record in a database`? you exit you `while` loop after first iteration either showing `user not found` of showing user's information if first row of result set matches input. And BTW why don't you filter data in the database using `WHERE` clause in SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

The [`PreparedStatement#executeQuery()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery()) method does not take any parameters.  Change this:

```
ResultSet rst = sta.executeQuery(query);
```

to this:

```
ResultSet rst = sta.executeQuery();
```

This is a somewhat common mistake when using this API.  You may have other issues with your code as well, but this should make a noticeable improvement.